# Distance between the spans of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, projection-matrices, matrix-norms

We have two matrices of the same dimension, $V_1$ and $V_2$. We take 
$$
P_i=V_i(V_i^tV_i)^{-1}V_i^t.
$$
Then we take the Frobenius norm (Hilbert Schmidt norm) of $P_1-P_2$. Why does this not change even if one changed any of the $V_i$ to $V_i'$ as long as they span the same space. Moreover, I always get this distance to be between 0 and 2 when $V_i$ has two columns. Why is that? Thank you.

You may wish to see `julia` code demonstration [here](https://gist.github.com/ztyh/b22c4c7326b4aaecb8698a3ac6175df9).

The Frobenius norm of a matrix is the square root of the sum of the squares of the elements.

Feedback from Kusma.
$$
VM(M^tV^tVM)^{-1}M^tV^t
$$
is same as $V(V^tV)^{-1}V^t$ for $M$ full rank. So first part is solved. Thanks.

Comment: If its an invertible square matrix, yes. So the distance between any two such matrix is 0. Which makes sense. In general the $V_i$ is not square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_1$ and $P_2$ are projections ($P_i^2=P_i$), so they are determined by the space they project onto. That the squared distance is bounded by the rank (I assume that the distance will get larger if you take $5\times4$ matrices instead of $4\times2$) is connected to the fact that all eigenvalues of projections are $0$ or $1$.

Your projections also satisfy $P_i^t=P_i$, so the matrix $P_1-P_2$ is diagonalisable with respect to some orthonormal basis. The eigenvalues all satisfy $-1\le \lambda_j\le 1$, so the square of the Frobenius norm is bounded by the size of the matrix.

Comment: You are right. I changed the matrix in the `julia` code to a 6 by 3 matrix. The distance between two orthogonal spans were larger than 2 but it was also not 3.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So if $V$ was 6 by 3, you showed $d\le 6$. Because $P$ is 6 by 6.

Comment: Sorry it was below $\sqrt{6}$. Thanks!